# Сканирование директорий

Tags: javascript, java, c#

Ребята есть ли какой то сканер с выбором директорий для сканирования файлов определенного формата написанном на любом языке программирования (по возможности на java)

Answer (score 0):

```
  public List<string> Files = new List<string>(); // сюда будут добавятся результат поиска
```

1. метод для поиска
2. string sDir = путь к паке в которой искать
3. string extention = раширение файлов для поиска

   ```
    public void DirSCan(string sDir,string extention)
               {
                   foreach (var f in Directory.GetFiles(sDir))
                   {
                       var tmpExt = Path.GetExtension(f);
                       if (tmpExt == extention)
                           Files.Add(f);
                   }
                   foreach (var d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
                       DirSearch(d);
               }
   ```

пример поиска :

```
DirSCan("c:\\",".txt")
```